# What are the different effects that different washes produce in baked goods?

Tags: baking, decorating

Just before you put something with dough in the oven, often you have to brush it with a liquid.
I've seen recipes that say with egg wash, with egg yolk, with egg white, with milk etc.

Does it make a difference what you use for brushing? If yes, what is best suited for what purpose (shining, browning, I don't know what else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best resource I've seen is here at [The Fresh Loaf](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/lessons/glazing).

- Egg yolk produces a shiny and dark look but remains soft.
- Egg white is still soft but less shiny.
- Milk and water only darken it slightly and produce what the article calls a 'satin' look.
- Butter makes it shiny, smooth, rich, and well, buttery!

Comment: I'd post the excellent picture there, but I'm not sure about the copyright issues associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

As the question is very broad, it's hard to give a comprehensive answer.

1. Whole beaten egg. You put it on the pastry before you put it in the oven for the browning and shining effect.
2. Beaten egg yolk. Gives a more yellow effect. Look at Gordon Ramsay on Youtube [making a Steak Wellington](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1orR1HGv0s) (1:34').
3. Beaten egg white. After baking the base you can paint it with egg white, put it another minute in the oven to protect the base from a more liquid filling.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does the beating make a difference?

Comment: @Mien: I'm not sure how you'd brush something with non-beaten egg. Needs to be a homogeneous, liquid-y mixture before you can brush with it.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I meant with the egg white and perhaps the yolk (if it's broken). And I'm not sure if it's a language thing, but by beating, I understand whisking it well with adding a bit of air; not just mixing it.

Comment: @Mien: A beaten egg is just that - beaten. Incorporating air would be *whipping* it.

Comment: Oh yes of course. It's just a language thing then. (the Dutch word for 'whipping' is literally 'beating')